# quantstrat and add.rule: the inner working of the orderqty argument

Tags: r, quantstrat

Digging into quantstrat and have it working. If it set `trade = 1000` at the start of a simulation and then run it, I get different results when an exit rule using `add.rule` has the argument `orderqty = trade*-1` to when it has `orderqty = "all"`.

Essentially, why can `orderqty = trade*-1` on an exit order trigger a short buy? Now that I have asked the question, perhaps my question is really about the role of `type =`  in `add.rule`.

Thanks

I have read all documentation and cannot find an answer (that I can understand). The documentation clearly states that 'type = 'exit'' is to exit a position.

Comment: Hi Aaron Simmons, welcome to SO. It is important to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks